# Regex in Java: a*

Tags: java, regex, metacharacters

Do you know why in a simple regex pattern if put a*(*quantifier) it does not match any result in the matcher even though it actually contains the character a; (in any case it should give back a result of having found an empty string as I am using "*").
It works with other characters, for instance with r* and b* there is no problem.
I am aware that it works if the content is put between quotes or parentheses.("a*").
Though just curious to know why it would work with b* without quotes and not with a* without quotes.

Code:

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(args[0]);
        Matcher match = pat.matcher(args[1]);
while (match.find())
        {
            System.out.println("Indeed this the information I need:"+ match.group());

            System.out.println("Here it starts:"+match.start());
}
```

I am aware that 'a' is a metacharacter but also 'e' and 'f' are and with them it works normally.

I insert as inputs : args[0] = a* args[1] = abba  in the command line.

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably because the `*` is getting expanded by the shell from which you are running Java. Try printing out the contents of `args[0]`, I think you'll find that the pattern you're matching against isn't the one you think you're matching against.

You could fix this by quoting your argument - `'a*'` instead of just `a*`.

Comment: Hi Amber, you are right! but why it happens!? it was expanded in animable.class a class file of an interface i created time ago. Is there any way to clear that cache of unwanted shortcuts in the shell?

Comment: `*` is a wildcard that's built into the shell, not a specific shortcut. `a*` to the shell means "any files in the current directory that start with `a`". You need to quote your arguments if you don't want wildcards to be expanded.

Answer (score 0):

In order to select something your regex has to be like: `"(a*)"` and you are interested in `group(1)`